# Odoo You should upgrade your version of Wkhtmltopdf to at least 0.12.0

Tags: debian, odoo-8, qweb

I'd like to print a report on Odoon8, I created my report using Qweb technologies, but i've received an error message

> You should upgrade your version of Wkhtmltopdf to at least 0.12.0 in order to get a correct display of headers and footers as well as support for table-breaking between pages.

Then i've installed Wkhtmltopdf version 0.9.9-4, This the details of Wkhtmltopdf package

[image]

I use debian 7.0, and Odoo 8, any help
thank in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using 0.9 you need to uninstall this and install atleast 0.12

```
sudo apt-get remove wkhtmltopdf
sudo apt-get purge wkhtmltopdf
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove wkhtmltopdf

sudo wget http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.3/wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz

sudo tar -xvf *.tar.xz

cd /wkhtmltox/bin

sudo mv wkhtmltopdf  /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```